# Radeon Cayman - Suddenly "gpu lockup"

Tags: linux, debian, gpu, radeon

my system has been running fine for > 2 years now in unchanged configuration (but updates).
Now today my computer locked up the first time with a "gpu lockup".

I checked and I did not do any updates lately (last 10 days).
Sometimes the computer runs fine until I lock it (and the screens turn off), sometimes it wouldn't even start or display the bios screen....
After a few retries the pc starts again. The fans are spinning and the card does not get too warm.

Can this be a hardware fault? I am very puzzeled because I have changed nothing and now it seems all broken :/ Any hints on going on further?

Thank you in advance.

My system is debian 10 with kernel 4.19.146-1

Here is my kernel log:
https://pastebin.com/eYNrMXTC